# JavaFX + How to get the length and height of the chart plot section?

Tags: javafx, charts, javafx-8, linechart

Can anyone let me know how I can find the length and height of the visible plot section in JavaFX charts (say `LineChart`).

In other words, I want to find the length(in px) between axis lowerBound and upperBound.

Please refer to the below screenshot.

Thanks.

[image: Refer to Screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your axes are instances of [`ValueAxis`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/ValueAxis.html), you can do:

```
double xMin = xAxis.getDisplayPosition(xAxis.getLowerBound());
double xMax = xAxis.getDisplayPosition(xAxis.getUpperBound());
double width = xMax - xMin ;

double yMin = yAxis.getDisplayPosition(yAxis.getUpperBound());
double yMax = yAxis.getDisplayPosition(yAxis.getLowerBound());
double height = yMax - yMin ;
```